# Clicking tab to navigate through input fields skips 'Title' in 'story view'

Tags: bug, developer-story

I tried to edit my profile, so I clicked on `Display Name`, and as usual, followed navigation through the fields using the tab key. It jumped as expected to `Real name`, but then it jumped to `Where you live`, instead of `Title`, where I would have expected it.

In addition, when clicking the `Title` field, a form displays but when typing some experience, it has another wrong behavior (in my opinion). Clicking tab jumps to the home icon in the top left (I guess the html tags are wrongly ordered? just trying to guess) and clicking enter saves the form automatically.

[image]

It just felt a bit weird so I had to share it.